# Brew doctor asking to update xcode, while its already updated

Tags: macos, xcode, install, homebrew

When I run brew doctor It says

```
Warning: Your Xcode (6.4) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 7.3.1.
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

While I already have latest XCode cli, which I found out by running `pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables` which says:

```
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 7.3.1.0.1.1461711523
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1466534515
groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group com.apple.DevToolsBoth.pkg-group com.apple.DevToolsNonRelocatableShared.pkg-group
```

How to I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is just simply that `brew` is detecting an old version of Xcode. If it was objecting to the version of the command line tools that you have installed you'd be getting a different error message.

```
A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.
```

You can see the actual code [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/fd0a81399b91afcca791847af87e2567dfdf374e/Library/Homebrew/extend/os/mac/diagnostic.rb) yourself. The checks for Xcode and the command line tools are separate.

The way to fix this message from `brew doctor` is either to remove the old version of Xcode or update it.